# Class “Mage_Framework_Helper_Data” not foun in app/Mage.php whle listing products on main page

Tags: php, helper, magento-1.8

I installed magento, added some products and displayed them on my main page. I was able to view this products on my main site. After this is switched from my default magento theme to the new and the products which were first seen doesn't load any more.

When looked at apache logs its shows me following error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/example/app/Mage.php on line 547, referer: http://example/index.php/?___SID=U&mode=list
```

I m new to magento, have no idea what this means. Searched but couldn't find a relative link which could solve this.

Comment: Does this help? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/fatal-error-class-mage-framework-helper-data-not-found-in-app-mage-php-when-c

Comment: No there isn't any `local` in my `app/code`